# Article on using Firebird.NET in a WinForms application

Tags: .net, firebird

Can anyone provide me with a link to good article about using Firebird.NET with a WinForms application? A simple google search did not yield good results - I am looking for a step-by-step guide which will help me to quickly a few things and am not sure the documentation is a good place to start.

Thanks in advance.
Anindya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of my links are a bit dated, but I think much of it still applies:

http://firebirdsql.org/firebirdtutorial/index.html
http://codemuch.com/?q=book/export/html/6    (I can't vouch for this one, it's a lot of code - as to the quality, well, take a look)